# Eclipse Can't Remove Android Dependencies Grayed Out

Tags: android, eclipse

My Android Project Dependencies are Grayed Out.  Which means I have two jar files that need to go and there is nothing I seem to be able to do about it. Or is there? Justed check .classpath and I don't see the settings there.  Were are they?